# C++ portable array serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, boost-serialization

On a project I work on, I have to send arrays of float / double back and forth over a network, I'm using Boost.Asio for the network stuff, as I need the communication to be async, and that just seemed to be the best (the only real one?) out there...

The arrays sent are floats / doubles, and the type is known to both sides. AFAIK, there are possible problems with the floating point storage standards + the same stuff that goes on with longs/ints, endians etc.

Logically, the arrays sent are dense matrices, handled by Eigen on one end, using BLAS / [MKL|ATLAS] and whatnot on the other end, quite possible that other uses will be needed, so I'm going for the most generic way possible & that seems to be passing around arrays.

The key requirement is high performance and portability, as both the client and server could possibly be run on any combination of 32 / 64 bit and the communication is pretty intense (real-time monitoring, refreshes every-something-seconds for the client), so the serialization overhead itself has to be minimal.

From what I have found so far, the two big players to consider here are Boost.Serialization and Google's Protobuf.

The big pro for BS is that I use Boost quite alot already in the project (though unit testing is in Google Test) and it seems to be really simple to serialize the array using `make_array()`. The big con for it is performance.

The advantage for protobuf from what I found is performance, all the benches seem to show that it outperforms BS by a factor of 10-20 on ANY operation. What I didn't find in the protobuf docs though is adding an array to the message. It uses repeated fields, and from what I understand, I'd have to use `MsgObject.repeatedProp.Add(const T&)` on each element of the array, which would mean, i.e., 10k calls to it for a 10k array, and that seems kindof costly too.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this would be highly appreciated, as my experience with C++ is limited and I've only recently restarted writing in it after a longer break...

Comment: I can't comment on the C++ api for adding items (I avoid that need in my C# version, but that won't help you) - but just to say; if you *do* look at protobuf, this seems a good use-case for "packed arrays" (which avoids the overhead of a header per element). Just a tip for squeezing out some extra performance.

Comment: If you really need super-high performance and all your clients are x86/x64, you could just write the binary data out directly. Floats and doubles take 4 and 8 bytes, respectively, with no padding (unline long double), so they look the same on both platforms. It's not exactly "portable", but practically it should work.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I'd thought of that, but I remember reading somewhere that reinterpret_cast is compiler implementation dependant, which would really mess with the portability thing...

Comment: @TC1: If you can spare half an hour, why not try and see if it works? I'm pretty sure that casting to `char*` **is** well-defined (for exactly this purpose), so I'm confident that you won't be disappointed. Add a checksum to the transmission anyway: `[size|**|**|...|**|checksum]`.

Comment: Kerrek is absolutely right. You can reinterpret_cast a float* or a double* to a char*. That gives you access to the underlying bytes, and lets you do such things as byte swapping. (I have done it on all sorts of platforms from MSVC to ARM compilers for mobile devices.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB It's not a half an hour thing, if I could test it right now, I would. The thing has to work & compile on at least GCC, MSVC and ICC, and at home I only have GCC. Could get MSVC, can't in any way get ICC for the next week or so.

Answer (score 2):

With protobufs, you can void the 10k calls to it for a 10k array if you encode the array using "bytes" instead of "repeated int32" (or similar).
In your code, if you cast pointers and use memcpy, it is usually very fast.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to boost asio, you might want to look at boost.MPI (message passing interface).  This uses boost.serialization for the serialization behind the scenes.

Boost.mpi [discusses](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.performance_optimizations) the performance optimisations that are possible for booost.serialization.  In particular, the use of

- BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(gps_position,track_never)
- BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(gps_position,object_serializable)

macros, and the mpi-defined macro

- BOOST_IS_MPI_DATATYPE(gps_position)

These optimisations seem to work well, see [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/mpi/performance.html) graph.

I have never used protobuff so I can't speak for this.

Comment: I really don't need MPI, at least not at this point, but thanks for the tip on BS, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There are good examples of this being done available on github. Here are some possible resources for going to and from protocol buffers eigen, and matrices:

- [HAL](https://github.com/arpg/HAL) hardware abstraction library (robotics).
- [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) does much the same thing with tensors (nd array) but their implementation will likely be much more complex considering the expansive feature set they support.
- [NUbots](https://github.com/NUbots/NUbots/blob/9543310f1acb4972f6bbba04e6acb5b29b9a72e5/nuclear/message/proto/Matrix.proto) has another example.
- [Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr_1/cc/proto/gfx_conversions_unittest.cc) seems to also have examples.
- [ceres-solver](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver) used to support [protobufs for matrices](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/5d00bf40f597e6b4542972fb81b3e1c93ea0cb73/internal/ceres/matrix.proto) but that functionality has since been removed. ([header](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver/blob/5d00bf40f597e6b4542972fb81b3e1c93ea0cb73/internal/ceres/matrix_proto.h))

Here is the HAL version, which is simple and looks like it will do pretty well:

[Protobuf for storing a matrix](https://github.com/arpg/HAL/blob/master/HAL/Messages/Matrix.proto):

```
package hal;

message MatrixMsg {
  required uint32 rows = 1;
  // columns deduced by division. Data stored as column major
  repeated double data = 2 [packed=true];
}

message VectorMsg {
  repeated double data = 1 [packed=true];
}
```

[Loading into eigen and writing to protobuf](https://github.com/arpg/HAL/blob/master/HAL/Messages/Matrix.h):

```
#pragma once

#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <HAL/Messages.pb.h>

namespace hal {

inline void ReadMatrix(const MatrixMsg &msg, Eigen::MatrixXd* mat) {
  mat->resize(msg.rows(),msg.data_size()/msg.rows());
  for(int ii = 0 ; ii < msg.data_size() ; ii++){
    mat->operator()(ii) = msg.data(ii);
  }
}

inline void ReadVector(const VectorMsg &msg, Eigen::VectorXd* vec) {
  vec->resize(msg.data_size());
  for(int ii = 0 ; ii < msg.data_size() ; ii++){
    vec->operator()(ii) = msg.data(ii);
  }
}

inline void WriteMatrix(const Eigen::MatrixXd &mat, MatrixMsg *msg) {
  msg->set_rows(mat.rows());
  msg->mutable_data()->Reserve(mat.rows()*mat.cols());
  for(int ii = 0 ; ii < mat.cols()*mat.rows() ; ii++){
    msg->add_data(mat(ii));
  }
}

inline void WriteVector(const Eigen::VectorXd &mat, VectorMsg *msg) {
  msg->mutable_data()->Reserve(mat.rows());
  for(int ii = 0 ; ii < mat.rows() ; ii++){
    msg->add_data(mat(ii));
  }
}

}  // namespace hal
```

However if you're going to do it across libraries there is more you'll have to account for. There was one other library that had a good implementation, where there were enums for the types, width, height and then a byte array, rowmajor/colmajor etc. However I cannot locate it again. These will have to be accounted for and included in the protobuf to be compatible across matrix libraries. For some ideas on how to do this the [HAL image protobuf](https://github.com/arpg/HAL/blob/master/HAL/Messages/Image.proto) and [image cpp](https://github.com/arpg/HAL/blob/master/HAL/Messages/Image.cpp) may help, which read/write from opencv sources which can also be considered to be a matrix.